# Cordova plugin background mode

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am beginner in apps creation area with cord. Already searched all over the internet but did not find any tutorial that explains exactly how to use the plugin to the background, in all questions that I have seen here are the same answers I I can not understand hope you can help me come on.

I am creating an application in cord that controls the user's diet with pre schedules set by the own application stating the time to eat and other things, the application is working 100% but only works alarms when it is open, I need it to work well after the user presses the back button on android I found this plugin on Github:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#usage

I tried to run the command line:

```
Cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode --searchpath path
```

but this line add any folder on GitHub Master within the plugin folder and I do not know what to do with these files, anyone could help me and tell you exactly where to put the files and where to call each of the files?

I am grateful the help of all, thank you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin that you are looking for is called 'cordovaLocalNotification'

Here you have documentaion:

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/

Good luck!